# Bitbake how to downgrade version of glibc used?

Tags: glibc, bitbake

I need to downgrade the version of glibc in the project that is built by bitbake.
Currently, bitbake uses glibc2.28 for the project build. What do I need to do in order bitbake would use glibc2.24 in the build(instead glibc2.28)?

Answer (score 0):

`GLIBCVERSION` is give in the file `poky/meta/conf/distro/include/tcmode-default.inc`. You can switch to `morty` branch as `glibc_2.24` is available as part of morty branch of opemembedded. Updating version manually would require copying recipes of particular version and other adaptions for compatiblity